# SimpleImputer with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, imputation

Let's suppose the following dataset

|  | code | category | energy | sugars | proteins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01 | B | 936 | NaN | 7.8 |
| 1 | 02 | NaN | NaN | 15.0 | NaN |
| 2 | 03 | A | 1569.0 | 23 | 4.1 |
| 3 | 04 | NaN | 826 | NaN | 3 |
| 4 | 05 | B | 1345 | 22 | 5.1 |
| 5 | 06 | A | NaN | 17 | NaN |
| 6 | 10 | C | 826 | NaN | 3 |
| 7 | 11 | C | 1345 | 26 | 5.1 |
| 8 | 101 | B | NaN | 18 | 6.1 |
| 9 | 102 | B | 636 | NaN | 7.8 |
| 10 | 103 | NaN | NaN | 15.0 | NaN |
| 11 | 104 | A | 1569.0 | 23 | 4.1 |
| 12 | 105 | C | 813 | NaN | 3.5 |

I would like to make the imputation with **SimpleImputer** considering the column `category`.

Namely, I would like to assign **the mean** considering the product's `category`.
If the product doesn't have a category, so, I would like to consider the mean of products without `category`.

So, to complete sugar for `code` 01.
I am only going to consider all `sugars` of products with `category` B

|  | code | category | energy | sugars | proteins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01 | B | 936 | NaN | 7.8 |
| 4 | 05 | B | 1345 | 22 | 5.1 |
| 8 | 101 | B | NaN | 18 | 6.1 |
| 9 | 102 | B | 636 | NaN | 7.8 |

I did something similar, as I show below. But I need to do it with **SimpleImputer**.
To clarify, in the case below, I completed the NaN without `category` with **the mean** of the column.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtypes == "float64":
        df.loc[df[col].isna() & df["category"].notnull(), col] = df["categories"].map(df.groupby("category")[col].mean())
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/42724040/10495893, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64048937/10495893

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you cannot use only `SimpleImputer` for this kind of problem (at least as far as I know).

However, you can create a custom class of Imputer using scikit-learn's very flexible classes `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`.

A very basic class would be something like the following:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class WithinGroupMeanImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, group_var):
        self.group_var = group_var
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
        
    def transform(self, X):
        # the copy leaves the original dataframe intact
        X_ = X.copy()
        for col in X_.columns:
            if X_[col].dtypes == 'float64':
                X_.loc[(X[col].isna()) & X_[self.group_var].notna(), col] = X_[self.group_var].map(X_.groupby(self.group_var)[col].mean())
                X_[col] = X_[col].fillna(X_[col].mean())
        return X_
```

---

On your sample dataset:

```
imp = WithinGroupMeanImputer(group_var='category')

imp.fit(df)

imp.transform(df)

   code category       energy     sugars  proteins
0    01        B   936.000000  20.000000  7.800000
1    02     None  1127.848485  15.000000  4.881818
2    03        A  1569.000000  23.000000  4.100000
3    04     None   826.000000  20.916667  3.000000
4    05        B  1345.000000  22.000000  5.100000
5    06        A  1569.000000  17.000000  4.100000
6    10        C   826.000000  26.000000  3.000000
7    11        C  1345.000000  26.000000  5.100000
8   101        B   972.333333  18.000000  6.100000
9   102        B   636.000000  20.000000  7.800000
10  103     None  1127.848485  15.000000  4.881818
11  104        A  1569.000000  23.000000  4.100000
12  105        C   813.000000  26.000000  3.500000
```

---

Original data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'code': ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '10', '11', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105'],
    'category': ['B', None, 'A', None, 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', None, 'A', 'C'],
    'energy': [936, None, 1569, 826, 1345, None, 826, 1345, None, 636, None, 1569, 813],
    'sugars': [None, 15, 23, None, 22, 17, None, 26, 18, None, 15, 23, None],
    'proteins': [7.8, None, 4.1, 3, 5.1, None, 3, 5.1, 6.1, 7.8, None, 4.1, 3.5]
})
```

Comment: You should probably learn the relevant statistics at `fit` time, so that test data doesn't impute using its own distribution.

Comment: Yeah you're right.. How should you implement it? Do you have a link to a guide where I can learn it?

Comment: In the questions I linked, I've also linked these two implementations: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/71856/55122 and https://towardsdatascience.com/coding-a-custom-imputer-in-scikit-learn-31bd68e541de

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will read them as soon as I can