# Scikit learn imputer in a pandas dataframe group by id

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe with the following data grouped by id and ordered by seq (note that some amounts are `nan`). I need to run scikit-learn imputer to impute the average by id.

```
from sklearn import impute
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rows  = [{'id': 1, 'seq': 0, 'amount': 2000 },
          {'id': 1, 'seq': 1, 'amount': 4000 },
          {'id': 1, 'seq': 2, 'amount': np.nan },
          {'id': 2, 'seq': 0, 'amount': 1000 },
          {'id': 2, 'seq': 1, 'amount': 3000 },
          {'id': 2, 'seq': 2, 'amount': np.nan }]

pdf = pd.DataFrame(rows)

imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')

# If I run this it will ignore the id
pdf[['amount_imputed']] = imputer.fit_transform(pdf[['amount']])
```

The result of amount_imputed should be 3000 for id = 1 and 2000 for id = 2. Instead, the statement above fills both amounts with the total average, 5000. How to group the imputer by id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scikit-learn impute mean of feature within groups of nominal value in another feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724040/scikit-learn-impute-mean-of-feature-within-groups-of-nominal-value-in-another-fe).  Also  https://stackoverflow.com/q/67515224/10495893

Comment: Not really, I'm looking for a groupby statement. Ynjxsjmh answer is almost there, I just need it to return a DataFrame instead of a Series, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try

```py
pdf['amount_imputed'] = (pdf.groupby('id', group_keys=False)['amount']
                         .transform(lambda col:
                             imputer.fit_transform(col.to_frame()).flatten(),
                         ))
# or
pdf['amount_imputed'] = (pdf.groupby('id', group_keys=False)
                         .apply(lambda g: pd.Series(
                             imputer.fit_transform(g[['amount']]).flatten(),
                             index=g.index
                         )))
```

```
print(pdf)

   id  seq  amount  amount_imputed
0   1    0  2000.0          2000.0
1   1    1  4000.0          4000.0
2   1    2     NaN          3000.0
3   2    0  1000.0          1000.0
4   2    1  3000.0          3000.0
5   2    2     NaN          2000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, using `SimpleImputer` we can't solve this kind of problem like group based. But there are some alternatives.

you can try this :

```
# Replace amount NaN with mean amount of same id
pdf['amount_imputed'] = pdf.groupby('id').amount.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
pdf.amount_imputed
```

Output :

```
0    2000.0
1    4000.0
2    3000.0
3    1000.0
4    3000.0
5    2000.0
Name: amount_imputed, dtype: float64
```